# merge of 2 data frames based on several columns defining 1 variable in r

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 data frame. Codes are: year, pd, treatm and rep.
Variablea are LAI in the first data frame, cimer, himv, nőv are in the second.
I would like to add variable LAI to the other variables/ columns.
I am not sure how to set the correct ordeing of LAI data, while 1 data has 4 codes to define.
Could You help me to solve this problem, please?
Thank You very much!

Data frames are:

```
> sample1
   year treatm pd rep  LAI  
1  2020      1  A   1 2.58
2  2020      1  A   2 2.08
3  2020      1  A   3 2.48
4  2020      1  A   4 2.98
5  2020      2  A   1 3.34
6  2020      2  A   2 3.11
7  2020      2  A   3 3.20
8  2020      2  A   4 2.56
9  2020      1  B   1 2.14
10 2020      1  B   2 2.17
11 2020      1  B   3 2.24
12 2020      1  B   4 2.29
13 2020      2  B   1 3.41
14 2020      2  B   2 3.12
15 2020      2  B   3 2.81
16 2020      2  B   4 2.63
17 2021      1  A   1 2.15
18 2021      1  A   2 2.25
19 2021      1  A   3 2.52
20 2021      1  A   4 2.57
21 2021      2  A   1 2.95
22 2021      2  A   2 2.82
23 2021      2  A   3 3.11
24 2021      2  A   4 3.04
25 2021      1  B   1 3.25
26 2021      1  B   2 2.33
27 2021      1  B   3 2.75
28 2021      1  B   4 3.09
29 2021      2  B   1 3.18
30 2021      2  B   2 2.75
31 2021      2  B   3 3.21
32 2021      2  B   4 3.57
> sample2
   year.pd.treatm.rep.cimer.himv.nőv
1                2020,A,1,1,92,93,94
2                2020,A,2,1,91,92,93
3                2020,B,1,1,72,73,75
4                2020,B,2,1,73,74,75
5               2020,A,1,2,95,96,100
6                2020,A,2,2,90,91,94
7                2020,B,1,2,74,76,78
8                2020,B,2,2,71,72,74
9                2020,A,1,3,94,95,96
10               2020,A,2,3,92,93,96
11               2020,B,1,3,76,77,77
12               2020,B,2,3,74,75,76
13               2020,A,1,4,90,91,97
14               2020,A,2,4,90,91,94
15               2020,B,1,4,74,75,NA
16               2020,B,2,4,73,75,NA
17               2021,A,1,1,92,93,94
18               2021,A,2,1,91,92,93
19               2021,B,1,1,72,73,75
20               2021,B,2,1,73,74,75
21              2021,A,1,2,95,96,100
22               2021,A,2,2,90,91,94
23               2021,B,1,2,74,76,78
24               2021,B,2,2,71,72,74
25               2021,A,1,3,94,95,96
26               2021,A,2,3,92,93,96
27               2021,B,1,3,76,77,77
28               2021,B,2,3,74,75,76
29               2021,A,1,4,90,91,97
30               2021,A,2,4,90,91,94
31               2021,B,1,4,74,75,NA
32               2021,B,2,4,73,75,NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inner_join` from `dply`

```
library(tidyverse)
inner_join(sample2,sample1, by=c("year","pd", "treatm", "rep"))
```

Output (first six lines)

```
   year pd treatm rep cimer himv nov  LAI
1: 2020  A      1   1    92   93  94 2.58
2: 2020  A      2   1    91   92  93 3.34
3: 2020  B      1   1    72   73  75 2.14
4: 2020  B      2   1    73   74  75 3.41
5: 2020  A      1   2    95   96 100 2.08
6: 2020  A      2   2    90   91  94 3.11
```

You can also use `data.table`

```
sample2[sample1, on=.(year,pd,treatm,rep)]
```